# How do I get nth term in a Sympy expression?

Tags: python, sympy

I have a sympy expression (of type <class 'sympy.core.add.Add'>)

```
expr = a + b + c + d
```

I want to do something like

```
third_term = expr[2]
third_term # which should give me a Sympy expression c
```

or

```
expr[2] = x
expr # which should give me a Sympy expression a + b + x + d
```

How do I do what I said above?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few issues here:

- When creating an expression, sympy doesn't take it literally, but automatically converts it to an internal format. This might change the order of the variables, and also take together for example `c + c` as `2*c`.
- Sympy expressions are immutable. This means you can't change them in-place: you always need to create a new expression. (This is similar to e.g. Pythons tuples, which also need to be created again when one wants to change them.)

Here is some code to illustrate what can happen:

```py
from sympy.abc import a, b, c, d, x

expr = a + b + c + d + c
print("The arguments of", expr, "are", expr.args)
print("The second argument is", expr.args[2])
new_expr = expr.func(*expr.args[:2], x, *expr.args[3:])
print("New expreession:", new_expr)

from sympy.abc import a, b, c, d, x

expr = a + b + c + d + c
print("The arguments of", expr, "are", expr.args)
print("The third argument is", expr.args[2])
new_expr = expr.func(*expr.args[:2], x, *expr.args[3:])
print("New expression:", new_expr, "with as arguments:", new_expr.args)
```

Output:

```
The arguments of a + b + 2*c + d are (a, b, d, 2*c)
The third argument is d
New expression: a + b + 2*c + x with as arguments: (a, b, x, 2*c)
```

It is not completely clear what the ultimate goal of the question is. Possibly you store your expressions as Python lists (these are mutable). And use `sum(your_list)` when they are needed as single sympy expressions.